# How to use admob NATIVE Ads in React-Native?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, admob

I need to use AdMob native ads in my React Native project, but I am unable to find a package for it. All the packages that are available include every type of ad except for AdMob native ads. How can I use Google native ads in React Native? Which package should I use for this? The package I am currently using is giving me an error: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-admob-native-ads.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using react-native-google-mobile-ads library https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-google-mobile-ads.

Comment: This package doesn't support NATIVE ads, it does Banner, interstitial etc. If anyone has any ideas RE AdMob and Native ads -  i am also looking (like the OP). There seems to be no obvious documentation or library.

Answer (score 0):

This package supports native ads
https://github.com/ammarahm-ed/react-native-admob-native-ads

You can also use it with Expo EAS build.